# Angular ng-repeat <li> string line feed

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

view:

```
<li ng-repeat='msg in msgs'>{{msg}}</li>
```

controller:

```
msgs=['abc','a
             b
             v', '123']

msgs.push('Something input from textarea, maybe has line feed')
```

wants:

> - abc
> - a
>   b
>   v
> - 123

but result line feed gone

> - abc
> - a b v
> - 123

try resolve

```
try refactoring < li> label to <myli>

app.directive('myli', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: "<li></li>",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.append(scope.msg);
        }
    }
});
```

**but not what i want, it just change initial data.**

**if i push something to msgs with line feed, line feed will change to space.**

**help me**

Comment: that's the way html works by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSS [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property...

```js
angular.module('so', []).run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.msgs = ['abc', `a
             b
             v`, '123'];

  $rootScope.msgs.push('Something input from textarea, maybe has line feed')
});
```

```css
li {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<ul ng-app="so">
  <li ng-repeat="msg in msgs">{{msg}}</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh.my god! I want directive <li> label, how stupid am i! It works, just one css to solve the problem that troubled me a few days. thank you very much.